# Why there is error while predicting using inceptionv3 pretrained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using Inception v3 pre-trained model

Images.shape is (15000,75,75,3)

[image]

But when I used model.predict I had gotten this error:

Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected shape=(None, 75, 75, 3), found shape=(None, 75, 3)

Comment: Always post code instead of images. We can't copy paste images and experiment with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img = images[0].reshape((1,75,75,3));
res = model.predict(img);
```

The first parameter is the number of samples that you will give. So, the model took the first (75) as the number of samples. Then, for the first sample, the model expects the input_shape (75,75,3) but it found (75,3). For that, you should provide the number of samples in the first dimension then the input_dimension.